# VHDL: Concise formulation of conditional signal assignment

Tags: syntax, vhdl

The following code is a 4:1 multiplexer. If the `dis` signal is '1' then the output should be 0 on all output pins. Is there a concise way to state that if `dis` is high, then the output should be 0, regardless of `sel`, without
having to permute through each combination of `sel`?

I am aware that in some cases, if conditional assignment are left ambiguous, then there becomes potential for unintended latch generation, and other undesired side effects.

```
architecture dataflow of mux8_4 is
begin
    q <=d0 when sel = "00" and dis = '0' else
        d1 when sel = "01" and dis = '0' else
        d2 when sel = "10" and dis = '0' else
        d3 when sel = "11" and dis = '0' else
        "00000000" when sel = "00" and dis = '1' else
        "00000000" when sel = "01" and dis = '1' else
        "00000000" when sel = "10" and dis = '1' else
        "00000000" when sel = "11" and dis = '1';
end architecture dataflow;
```

My attempt (I understand the omission of all possible statements to be bad
practice, however)

```
architecture dataflow of mux8_4 is
begin
    q <=    "00000000" when dis = '1' else
        d0 when sel = "00" and dis = '0' else
        d1 when sel = "01" and dis = '0' else
        d2 when sel = "10" and dis = '0' else
        d3 when sel = "11" and dis = '0';
end architecture dataflow;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's also selected signal assignment:

```
architecture foo of mux8_4 is
    subtype choice_type is std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
begin
    with choice_type'(dis & sel) select
        q <= d0          when "000",
             d1          when "001",
             d2          when "010",
             d3          when "011",
             "00000000"  when others;
end architecture;
```

Where the case expression may be a qualified expression with a type mark that has a locally static subtype.

See IEEE Std 1076-1993 9.5.2 Selected signal assignments, 8.8 Case statement or IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.6 Concurrent signal assignment statements, 10.5.4 Selected signal assignment statements, 10.9 Case statement.

This (and your) concurrent signal assignment statements have equivalent processes containing equivalent sequential signal assignment statements. Both conditional and selected signal assignment statements are allowed as sequential statements in -2008. There is an equivalent case statement for a selected signal assignment.

Providing only binary values for dis and select can be done for synthesis where the weak values 'H' and 'L' are mapped to the strong values '1' and '0' respectively. For simulation you can use conversion functions to insure dis and sel represent a binary value if they can have weak values.

If your four mux data inputs can be expresses as an array value you describe a multiplexer a little more compactly:

```
architecture fum of mux8_4 is
    type mux4 is array (0 to 3) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    signal mux:      mux4;
begin
    mux <= (d0, d1, d2, d3);
    q <= mux(to_integer(unsigned(sel))) when dis = '0' else (others => '0');

end architecture;
```

An index name requires an array object with a locally static name so a type declaration is used in declaring an array object (mux) that is assigned an aggregate value of type mux4.

After that we can use an index converted to a natural from sel as an index when dis = '0' in a conditional signal assignment, with an else value of all '0's.

Both of these architectures analyze. If you had provided a [Minimal, Complete and Veriable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with an entity declaration and a testbench they could have been elaborated and simulated, demonstrating functionality. (They both analyze with an added entity declaration).

If your sel signal had been a constrained integer subtype the indexed name index would be even more compact and readable. The to_integer conversion function found in package numeric_std maps weak levels representing binary values to strong and generates a warning if sel contains metavalue element values (which would be mapped to '0').